# textureMappingu/v in common Vertex structures?

Tags: c++, directx, texture-mapping

Looking through some directx examples, I'm often seeing the structure for a vertex to be defined as such:

```
struct Vertex
{
    vector position;
    vector normal;
    int textureMappingu;
    int textureMappingv;
}
```

Under this type of vertex, what are textureMappingu/v for?

Comment: Its worth noting that under DirectX a UV ought to be a float ...

Answer (score 4):

Used for texture mapping. Vector [u,v] is coordinate of vertex in texture space (2D texture obviously). One picture is worth more than thousand words in this case - see how each vertex is mapped onto texture and how is texture face "warped" so triangle areas has same texture resolution.

[alt text http://www.cheetah3d.com/img/about/uv_pic3.png](http://www.cheetah3d.com/img/about/uv_pic3.png)

If you need to know more - look for UV mapping.

Comment: +1 for the nice picture. The left part represents the texture used on the head, overlaid with each primitive of the head, in the UV space.